# How to use Scrubadub if a noun is not a name

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, data-cleaning

I want to use scrubadub on some text like: "Max is a Cat and wants some food from Steve".

When I used the code from [the documentation](https://scrubadub.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html), it gave me an output like this:

```
import scrubadub
text = u"Max is a Cat and wants some food from Steve"
scrubadub.clean(text)
```

> Out[57]: '{{NAME}} is a {{NAME}} and wants some food from {{NAME}}'

I do not want to show `Cat`, or any other noun that is not a name, as a Name. How can I change this?

Comment: Why is "Cat" capitalized if it's not a name?

Comment: That is just an example. Maybe New York instead Cat would be a better choice...

Comment: I have this same issue.

Comment: @kilord - you have probably moved on from this issue, but I found scrubadub_stanford handles this quite well.  https://scrubadub.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api_scrubadub_detectors.html#scrubadub-stanford-detectors-stanfordentitydetector